# Can anyone explain the "guardian pattern" to me

Tags: python, python-2.7, short-circuiting

Tried searching for guardian pattern but I couldn't find anything that answered my question so here I am again. In the book I am reading the author uses a line of code that he calls, "the guardian pattern" and I don't really understand how it works. here is the example and I would be grateful if someone could explain it to me.

```
while True:
    line = raw_input('> ')
    if len(line) > 0 and line[0] == '#' :
        continue
    if line == 'done':
        break
    print line
print "done!"
```

so why, if the length of the line > 0 and line[0] == '#' :
does it not error if I just hit enter with nothing there. Wouldn't the line be 0 and thus line isn't > 0? if you put the orig code in which is

```
if line[0] == '#' :
```

it errors out when you just hit enter.

Comment: Note that this whole pattern isn't actually needed here. You could make the test `if line.startswith('#'):` (or equivalently, but less idiomatically, `if line[:1] == '#':`) and it will work correctly whether or not the user entered anything, with a single conditional test, not two.

Comment: Which book did you see this in? I'm also seeing references to the Guardian pattern and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so why, if the length of the line > 0 and line[0] == '#' : does it not error if I just hit enter with nothing there.

No, it does not throw an error. Python uses lazy evaluation, which enables short circuiting with the `and` operator. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

In other words, the second part of the boolean expression, i.e., `line[0] == '#'`, only gets evaluated if the first part is `True`.

I believe this is the reason why that author calls this the *guardian pattern*, so that the first part of the expression avoids (*guards*) a possible error in the second part of the expression.

If you remove that first part, like in the example you show, then you would be trying to access the first element of `line` (`line[0]`), when there are none elements in `line`.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't the line be 0 and thus line isn't > 0?

If you just press enter line is `""` . An empty string. The length of this string `len(line)` is 0 (thus causing your program to continue as soon as the first case of the `and` statement is evaluated. If you access the first index `0` of an empty line, it will throw an error. Thus, always check if you actually have a first index before accessing it...

Answer (score 0):

I had just learned that, i think so, here is the definition i created for myself : a guardian pattern is a code that can cause an error but it doesn't, why? because python didn't complete executing the code, it did just run the correct part because that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The "guardian pattern" is a fancy way of saying "Check for things that will cause an error before you call a function."

Example:
If you ask for element 10 of an array, and the array has only 5 elements, it will give you an Index Error. The Guardian Pattern would check to make sure that the array has at least eleven elements (think about it) before you ask for my_array[10].

```
def somefunction(content):
    if len(content) > 11:
        return content[10]
    else:
        return None
```

The alternative would be to surround the code with a try/catch block. If you have numerous conditions that might cause a problem, and you don't care which of them is the problem, this will save you some nitpicking.

Honestly, I had to look this up. We just called this "validation" when I learned programming.

Answer (score -1):

```
if len(wds) < 3 or wds[0] != 'From' :
       continue
```

Comment: Please utilize markdown in your answers and explain why they work